# Looking for information on connect raspberry pi to ps2 console

Tags: gpio

I am wondering if anyone can tell me if it is possible or help point me ilin the right direction to information about connect a raspberry pi to a ps3 console and have it act like a controller.  I have tried looking it up but it seems it's more popular to do it the other way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would be really complicated, and as PS is not open-source, you won't be able to find any specifications on what PS3 looks for.

Comment: the info about emulating playstation controllers is on the web